# Symfony custom doctrine datetime type not working

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, sqlsrv

I have following configuration where I try to handle SQL Server 2008 running in 2005 compatibility mode, datetime quirks.

```
=== config.yml
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
  dbal:
    types:
      datetime2005: AppBundle\ORM\DBAL\DateTime2005Type



=== DateTime2005Type.php
namespace AppBundle\ORM\DBAL;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType as BaseDateTimeType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class DateTime2005Type extends BaseDateTimeType
{
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        die();
    }
}
```

Do note this **die()** there. It should stop execution of my app, right?

```
=== SomeEntity.php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="ErzDate", type="datetime2005", nullable=true)
 */
private $createdAt;
```

ss

```
=== Rendered SQL & error:
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT count(DISTINCT m0_.Ident) AS sclr0 FROM MedionOA3Requests m0_ WHERE m0_.Project LIKE ? AND m0_.ErzDate IS NOT NULL AND m0_.ErzDate >= ?' with params ["MANUALQUERY", "2016-02-13 00:00:00"]:

SQLSTATE [22007, 242]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Bei der Konvertierung eines nvarchar-Datentyps in einen datetime-Datentyp liegt der Wert außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs.
```

So my custom datetime was not loaded or, I'm implementing it wrong. Please, help.

- What is proper configuration for registering custom doctrine types?
- What functions should I (re)implement to make Doctrine use custom
  formatting for datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom types only work for persist and select expressions, not for `WHERE` clauses. This means the object will have the converted value after hydration.

[From the docs:](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/advanced-field-value-conversion-using-custom-mapping-types.html)

> When using DQL queries, the convertToPHPValueSQL and convertToDatabaseValueSQL methods only apply to identification variables and path expressions in SELECT clauses. Expressions in WHERE clauses are not wrapped!
>   If you want to use Point values in WHERE clauses, you have to implement a user defined function.

Maybe you can solve it by [using a custom function](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) as they suggest.

Comment: :Facepalm: Yes. That is it. In my Repo for that entity I was inserting manually constructed date in `Where`. Fixed that and it works again. Big thx.